# Python pandas implement conditional categories

Tags: python, conditional-statements, categories

In the following dataframe df:

```
Type  Description Counts
A        blue      34645
A        red       45765
B        red       36587
C        green     42653
```

I want to implement a category hierarchy, but only for Type A.

I am using this code:

```
category_hierarchy={
'blue':'in progress',
'red':'review'}

df['Category_Hierachy'] = df['Description'].replace(category_hierarchy)
```

However, this creates the following:

```
Type  Description Counts  Category_Hierachy
A        blue      34645    in progress
A        red       45765    review
B        red       36587    review
C       green      42653    green
```

INSTEAD OF

```
Type  Description Counts  Category_Hierachy
A        blue      34645    in progress
A        red       45765    review
B        red       36587    
C       green      42653
```

How can I apply my code to only rows with Type A?

Thank You

Comment: What's the `email` variable?

Comment: sorry, it should be df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using apply

```
def custom_apply(row):

    if row['Type'] == 'A':

        return category_hierarchy[row['Description']]

    return ''

df['Category_Hierachy'] = df.apply(custom_apply, 1)
```

or

## Using `isin`

```
idx = df['Type'].isin(['B', 'C'])
df.ix[idx, "Category_Hierachy"] = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `email` is a typo for `df` and I properly understand what you're trying to do: the blank spaces in the column you're adding will have to be filled with *some* value. You can't create a column that doesn't even have entries for certain rows. As long as that's okay, I recommend creating the new column with all values set to the "default" first, and only afterwards assigning to the rows where `Type` is `'A'`.

In terms of code, you can create a new column filled with empty strings as

```
df['Category_Hierarchy'] = ''
```

(substitute your default value of choice) and then you can reference only the rows of type A by using a boolean index.

```
index = df['Type'] == 'A'
df.loc[index, 'Category_Hierarchy'] = ...
```

That last line will assign to only the cells in column `Category_Hierarchy` which are in rows where `Type` is `'A'`.